# MOSFET driver not working

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, current, mosfet-driver

I'm having an issue with the [MIC4606-2YML](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC4606%20Evaluation%20Board%20UG%2050002980A.pdf) evaluation board.

There is no voltage waveform at the load side output connector during operation.
The bus voltage, VBUS, is at 24 VDC and the VDD voltage to the gate driver section is at 12 VDC.
The APWM and BPWM input signals are present (these are 180 degrees out of phase running at 12.5 kHz, both at 50% duty cycle) and the EN (enable) line is pulled up as expected. I had this working nicely yesterday using the PIC32MK MCM Curiosity Pro Dev Board. This morning, however, I do not see anything on the output. I have verified that the input PWM signals are present, the bus voltage is present, the ENABLE signal is high, and the MOSFETs appear to be "healthy" and non-shorted. Any thoughts on what might be causing the MIC4606-2 to not drive the full bridge FETs?

Comment: Maybe you broke it?

Comment: From the schematic, there should be test points TP2, TP3, TP7, and TP9 where you can check there is a signal going to each of the MOSFETS. Is there?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I've looked at test points you mentioned above, and there are no gate drive signals present on ANY of the MOSFET output stages. At this point, I believe that the MIC4606-2YML is damaged. What I am trying to understand is what was the root cause of the failure, or possible failure mechanisms? I've been digging deeper into the user guide for the development board and the datasheet. The user guide states to turn on VDD first (power to the MIC4606), then VIN (the bridge bus voltage).

Comment: @AndrewMorton,However, the datasheet shows a block diagram of a typical application circuit showing VIN feeding both the h-bridge bus and a switching power supply (MIC28511) which feeds the VDD of the gate driver. The MIC28511 has a 5mS soft start internal to the device. If we look at the voltage sequencing of the system, the implication is that VDD is delayed as VIN (aka bridge bus voltage, VBUS) is rising. Does VIN to the driver need to be present prior to a voltage being established on the h-bridge?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, The test circuit I constructed matched the block diagram shown in the datasheet, with a 12VDC switch mode power supply being supplied by VBUS and also having a 5mS soft start

Comment: @JohnD, i think I broke it. But trying to find the root cause

Comment: @Freshman I am by no means an expert in these matters, but it could have been just an unlucky static discharge in the wrong place if it was working when you left it and then it was broken the next day. Do you take any anti-static precautions?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thank you for the response. Yes, i did take anti static necessary precautions